# NSURLSession returns different response than browser would, why?

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurlsession

Any idea why `NSURLSession` returns this response:

> The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and
>   OAuth are supported

```
let username = "8r6nibK8Pe28WFhjTX1gGb1Rhhhc7xM02v7XKRPedL4"
let password = "8r6nibK8Pe28WFhjTX1gGb1Rhhhc7xM02v7XKRPedL4"
let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let authString = "Basic \(base64LoginString)"
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query='Rambo'+'Oscar'")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let a = NSURLSession(configuration: config).dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, urlResponse, error in

    if data != nil {

        let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(str)
    } else {
        _ = 7
    }
})

a.resume()
```

Browser returns different response with meaningful image information. And I am using basic authentication to send request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL to C# webrequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421061/curl-to-c-sharp-webrequest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may probably the option: `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength`. try:

```
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

To investigate use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see the difference in the requests. –  zaph 10 mins ago

Comment: You also should not be creating the Authorization header yourself.  The URL loading system provides built-in support for authentication, so the OS can stomp on that header at any time.